# NSArray of structures?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Trying to implement the following structure from "c" to use NSArray in objective-c:

In standard-c:

```
struct structDog{
    char *name;
    int age;
};

struct structLitter{
    struct structDog puppy[10];
};
```

Then I use malloc to allocate space.
But since I am using NSArray.

But in Objective-c I am using NSArray... so ???

```
NSArray struct structDog *puppy; // <<---this doesn't work
```

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you are trying to do is get your `struct` into your `NSArray` you need to use [NSValue](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValue_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  For instance you can do something like:

```
NSArray* myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSValue valueWithPointer: myDog],
                                             [NSValue valueWithPointer: myPuppy],
                                             nil];

structDog* dog = (structDog*)[[myArray objectAtIndex:0] pointerValue];
```

Comment: +1 Good answer... but, don't do that!   An Objective-C class has very little overhead.  Just define a class `Dog` and put the various attributes on it as `@property`s.  Not only will this fit better with the Cocoa APIs, but you'll end up with something that is much easier to refactor into a full blown object graph with persistence, logic, etc... later.

Comment: As @bbum said, this carries more overhead than simply using an object *and* has a lot of disadvantages even besides that, with practically no benefit.

Comment: @Chuck - Yes, I agree that it's better in general to just use proper objects.  But that's not what was asked, and there are cases where using objects might not be feasible such as when using a third-party C library that passes structs around.  In such cases using `NSValue` can be the only practical option, so it's good to be aware of it.

Comment: @aroth: I wasn't criticizing your answer, though I think it would have been worthwhile to mention `value:withObjCType` for directly storing struct values in the array rather than pointers to structs. I was mainly just pointing out the drawbacks inherent in this approach.